Object with only string or number keys in typescript, and not symbol
I am looking to force an object type to only contain string keys.
I tried a lot of things, here is my best bet:
type StrKeyObj<Obj extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>> = { [K in keyof Obj]: K extends string ? K : never }


export interface EventHandler<
  Method extends 'create' | 'update', 
  // I wish this type can be forced to an object with only string keys
  Models extends StrKeyObj
> {
  // so that I can use this pattern without an error
  on: `${keyof Models}.${Method}`, //  Type 'symbol' is not assignable to type 'string...'
  main(): void
}

Here is my typescript playground
It seems like an easy question but I didn't find any answers right now...

You can't prohibit symbol keys. All you can do is discourage them. But you don't even really care about that; you just want to ignore non-string keys in your type, so this approach is the standard way this is done. (You've got an XY problem; your actual use case is "write EventHandler" but you've decided "prohibit symbol keys" is the solution, but it isn't.) Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Thanks for this solution  Yes this can be an answer, thanks for your time

While I wouldn't call it a hard-and-fast rule, Postel's Law would suggest that you not prohibit callers from passing you an object with Symbol keys: you just filter them out in the body of the function (in a fashion that satisfies the compiler). You may want to prefer solutions like the one jcalz gave you in general.

You can't really prohibit keys in a TypeScript object type. The closest you can get is to say that keys you don't like must have values of the never type, which is close:
type NoSymbolKeys = {
  [k: string]: unknown,
  [k: symbol]: never;
}

const sym = Symbol();
let x: NoSymbolKeys;
x = { a: 1, b: 2 };
x = { a: 1, [sym]: 2 }; // error

But that's not really what you're looking for. Your use case is to use keyof in a template literal type and that still fails because you cannot ever be certain there's no symbol keys in some generic object type:
type Oops<T extends NoSymbolKeys> = `${keyof T}` // still error!


Instead, the standard approach here is to intersect your thing-which-might-have-symbols with string to tell the compiler that you only want to use the subset which are strings:
interface EventHandler<
  Method extends 'create' | 'update',
  Models extends object
> {
  on: `${string & keyof Models}.${Method}`, // okay
  main(): void
}

Playground link to code
